# I created my own editor with eclipse rcp concepts.But it is not being shown in the "Internal/External editor list in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I created my own editor by adding an extension point of org.eclipse.ui.editors
I need to always open files of particular extension with my editor.
The extension point structure is as shown:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
<editor
     class="testeditor.editors.ExampleEditor"
     extensions="min"
     icon="icons/alt_window16.gif"
     id="testeditor.editors.ExampleEditor"
     name="TestEditor">
 </editor>
```

But the problem is , whenever i try to open a file with extension specified above, i cannot find my editor in the editor list.Right-click file->Open with->Other(here my editor is not being shown)

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you actually installed the plugin in the Eclipse you are using for the workspace?

Comment: I am not sure of how to do that.Could you help?

Comment: I am able to do this now. I followed https://www.codeproject.com/tips/893547/how-to-create-your-own-eclipse-ide-plug-in. Thank you @greg-449 for the help.